# Magento 2:User Permission via API Rest

Tags: magento2, multistore, security, permissions

I have a multi-store magento 2 installation where the stores are totally independent, from different companies.

So, we have an integration with our ERP system in the company. Each user in our system has a specific permission only for your own store in frontend.

My problem is: a serious problem with security. A user can have access to another store by changing the store_id in REST API. Is there a way to block this?

reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/

Comment: You can not block this thing.
Because in frontend store is not restricted.
whatever ID that you will pass will be loaded.

Comment: But I am not saying its impossible you may try some alternative solutions 
Just suggesting that you may add force login on website so if a user logged then only they can see frontend 
so if user logged in then you can determine store of that user and you can restrict that user to view other stores on the website. (but it requires some customisation)